# Angularjs - jquery parents function equivalent?

Tags: angularjs

Jquery has a function - $elem.parents (http://api.jquery.com/parents/)
which allows you to find all the ancestors of an element containing a specific class.

Is there something similar to this in angularjs?

Comment: If jQuery is on your page, you can use it as `angular.element`, but you should probably only concern yourself with DOM manipulation in a directive. What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: yes, angularjs include jQLite which is nothing but smaller version of jquery..& it does contain `.parents()` method

Comment: Beautiful, thank you Mr.Mullins. Put it as an answer.